# Type of VCO that generates square waves

Tags: vco

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-controlled_oscillator), there are two types of VCOs.

> Linear or harmonic oscillators generate a sinusoidal waveform.

> Relaxation oscillators can generate a sawtooth or triangular waveform.

What are VCO ICs that generate square waves part of? I am referring to the [CD4046 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha002a/scha002a.pdf), which generates square waves. Is it a linear oscillator, or a relaxation oscillator?

[image]

Comment: 'what are they part of?' I don't understand your question. According to wikipedia, linear VCOs generates sine waves, relaxation VCOs generate square or triangular. 4046 generates square waves (and triangular at the capacitor terminals 6,7). So what type of VCO is a 4046?

Comment: Throw a comparator at any of said waveforms, and you have a square wave genarator.

Comment: The categorization in Wikipedia is not complete. For example they don't include ring oscillators,  which can be made into VCOs by varactor loading or by current starving a stage.